# Why this C++ code(from C++ Primer 5th 3.4.2) can't work right?

Tags: c++

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    vector<string> text = {"a", "v"};
    vector<string>::iterator beg = text.begin();
    vector<string>::iterator end = text.end();
    vector<string>::iterator mid = text.begin() + (end - beg) / 2;

    while (mid != end && *mid != "l") {
        if ("l" < *mid) {
            end = mid;
        } else {
            beg = mid;
        }
        mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;
    }

    if (*mid == "l")
        cout << "Have Found!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Not Found!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why it go to endless loop?Please Help me!I build the code in VisulStudio 2013 and Code::Block，But result all is bad!

Comment: What is the purpose of this code ?What are you trying to search for?

Comment: Is that a binary search ? with strings?

Comment: Because you copied it incorrectly. `beg = mid + 1;`

Comment: `Help me!I build the code in VisulStudio 2013 and Code::Block`  Don't waste time trying on another compiler if this trivial code doesn't work for one compiler.   What if the code did "work" for the second compiler?  That does *not* mean the code is ok, and the first compiler is wrong.  Don't fall into that trap -- your code doesn't work with Visual Studio, then fix it there.

Comment: @Sammer Sawla I hava said the code is from C++ primer 5th!

Comment: @vim_cpp : This is a badly written code. If you understand though how the language and constructs works, thats more necessary. These are certain things that you will understand with time. THat being said, look for binary search of numbers and you will see close similarity between what you are doing and what binary search does. Go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So OK I am scratching the solution because I think your algorithm was going wrong, which made `mid` to point the unidentified locations. What I have figured out is you were using `C++11`.Nevertheless, this solution would work fine.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void populateVector(vector<string> &text)
{
    for(int i=97;i<=118;i++)
    {
        text.push_back(string(1,(char)i));
    }
}

void printVector(vector<string> &text)
{
    for(int i=0;i<text.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<text[i]<<"\n";
    }
}

bool found(vector<string> &text,string &toBeFound)
{
    vector<string>::iterator beg = text.begin();
    vector<string>::iterator end = text.end();
    vector<string>::iterator mid ;

    while(beg<=end)
    {

        mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;
        //This piece of code had to be added 
        if(mid==end)
        {
         break;
        }
        //This piece of code had to be added 
        //@DEBUG: cout<<*mid<<"\n";
        if(*mid==toBeFound)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(*mid<toBeFound)
        {
            beg=mid+1;
        }
        else
        {
            end=mid-1;
        }
    }
    return false;

}

int main()
{

    vector<string> text;
    string toBeFound = "l";
    populateVector(text);
    printVector(text);

    if(found(text,toBeFound))
    {
        cout<<"Found\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Not Found\n";
    }



    return 0;
}
```

The program is self clear. Lemme know if you have any issues. I guess this should work.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much, but acoording your code, the result is Error that Expression: vector iterator not dereferencable!

Comment: @vim_cpp : Have changed my solution. Have a look

Comment: @Sammer Sawla : Hava you tried to test the case that the toBeFound is "w" or "y" or "z", hope you can correct the code!

Comment: @vim_cpp : thanks for pointing that out. Have corrected the code. Should work now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;` is the source of your problem. If you were to make the start of you while loop something like the following it should work.

```
while(++mid != end && *mid != "l")
```

`++mid` begin the key.

Comment: Nice try though. I don't think though that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`*mid` is always "a" Inside of your loop. This never meets the conditions to exit.

```
while (mid != end && *mid != "l") {
    if ("l" < *mid) {
        end = mid;
    } else {
        beg = mid+1; //Increment mid here to exit the loop;
    }
    mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but acoording your code, the result is Error that Expression: vector iterator not dereferencable!

Comment: Try again. Removed the cout<<.  It's exactly the same as your code, just with the increment.

Comment: @vim_cpp: Your final condition needs to match the while condition.  By failing to test whether `mid == end`, you create the possibility of dereferencing `end`.